# Have <audio> element play through earpiece

Tags: javascript, html, audio

In a webpage environment, is there a way to force the audio to play through the earpiece instead of through the loudspeaker as it does by default? Here is my code that plays the base64 encoded blob to the loudspeaker:

```
<p><audio id="audio" controls></audio></p>
<script>
// me saying "test"
var message = "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";

function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
  contentType = contentType || '';
  sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

  var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  var byteArrays = [];

  for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}
var blob = b64toBlob(message, "video/webm");
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  audio.play();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [`HTMLMediaElement.setSinkId()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId) to achieve this. Please note that that function is part of an experimental API. Only a few browsers (Chrome 49 and Opera 36) support it at the moment.

---

```
async function setupAudioOutput(audio) {
  const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  const audioDevices = devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'audiooutput');
  await audio.setSinkId(audioDevices[0].deviceId);
}
```

Call this function after your `<audio>` element was created and pass it as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it was a good one but unfortunately there is only one mediaDevice on my mobile (testing with Pixel Chrome) seems this isn't possible yet!